# Nested data with error "Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed)''

Tags: backpropagation, pytorch-dataloader

everyone, I am confused with the following experience with pytorch, I have nested data, and try to train a model with these nested data by two for loops. When I run the 'code A', the backward error occurs at the loss.backward() part at the i=0, j=1 in code A, which means the first run of inner loop is successfully done, but the second run of inner loop encounters an error at the loss.backward().  However, when I run the 'code B' (the only difference from code A is I didn't use the x_loader and y_loader.), no error happens.  Can anyone help to explain why this error happens in code A but does not happen in code B? Any suggestions or hints will be appreciated!

```
## code A ##
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader


x = torch.range(start=0, end=1, step=0.5)
x = torch.tensor(x, requires_grad=True).float()
y = torch.range(start=0, end=1, step=0.5)
y = torch.tensor(y, requires_grad=True).float()
x_loader = DataLoader(x, shuffle=True, batch_size=2)    
y_loader = DataLoader(y, shuffle=True, batch_size=2)    
print(f'x is: {x}')

loss = nn.MSELoss()

for i, x_ in enumerate(x_loader):
    print(f'{i}-th x is: {x_}')
    for j, y_ in enumerate(y_loader):
        print(f'{j}-th y is: {y_}')
        l = loss(x_, y_)
        print(f'l for {i, j} is: {l.item()}')
        l.backward()
        print(f'-----backward is completed for {i}-th x and {j}-th y')
```

here is the output and error report: Based on the output, we can

```
x is: tensor([0.0000, 0.5000, 1.0000], requires_grad=True)
0-th x is: tensor([1.0000, 0.5000], grad_fn=<StackBackward0>)
0-th y is: tensor([0.5000, 0.0000], grad_fn=<StackBackward0>)
l for (0, 0) is: 0.25
-----backward is completed for 0-th x and 0-th y
1-th y is: tensor([1.], grad_fn=<StackBackward0>)
l for (0, 1) is: 0.125

in backward
    Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed). Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call .backward() or autograd.grad(). Specify retain_graph=True if you need to backward through the graph a second time or if you need to access saved tensors after calling backward.
```

Below is 'code B'

```
## code B ##
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader


x = torch.range(start=0, end=1, step=0.5)
x = torch.tensor(x, requires_grad=True).float()
y = torch.range(start=0, end=1, step=0.5)
y = torch.tensor(y, requires_grad=True).float()
x_loader = DataLoader(x, shuffle=True, batch_size=2)    
y_loader = DataLoader(y, shuffle=True, batch_size=2)    
print(f'x is: {x}')

loss = nn.MSELoss()

for i, x_ in enumerate(x):
    print(f'{i}-th x is: {x_}')
    for j, y_ in enumerate(y):
        print(f'{j}-th y is: {y_}')
        l = loss(x_, y_)
        print(f'l for {i, j} is: {l.item()}')
        l.backward()
        print(f'-----backward is completed for {i}-th x and {j}-th y')
```

here is the output:

```
x is: tensor([0.0000, 0.5000, 1.0000], requires_grad=True)
0-th x is: 0.0
0-th y is: 0.0
l for (0, 0) is: 0.0
-----backward is completed for 0-th x and 0-th y
1-th y is: 0.5
l for (0, 1) is: 0.25
-----backward is completed for 0-th x and 1-th y
2-th y is: 1.0
l for (0, 2) is: 1.0
-----backward is completed for 0-th x and 2-th y
1-th x is: 0.5
0-th y is: 0.0
l for (1, 0) is: 0.25
-----backward is completed for 1-th x and 0-th y
1-th y is: 0.5
l for (1, 1) is: 0.0
-----backward is completed for 1-th x and 1-th y
2-th y is: 1.0
l for (1, 2) is: 0.25
-----backward is completed for 1-th x and 2-th y
2-th x is: 1.0
0-th y is: 0.0
l for (2, 0) is: 1.0
-----backward is completed for 2-th x and 0-th y
1-th y is: 0.5
l for (2, 1) is: 0.25
-----backward is completed for 2-th x and 1-th y
2-th y is: 1.0
l for (2, 2) is: 0.0
-----backward is completed for 2-th x and 2-th y

Process finished with exit code 0
```

in code A, if I set `loss.backward(require_grad=True)`, then, it can run without error. But I am confused why do I need to go back to the same graph twice? In my design, I don't expect backward twice on same graph. Based on my understanding, batches in the inner loop are independent to each other, and for each batch, once the loss is computed and the backward is processed, all of the immediate variables and graph of this batch should be useless so that being freed. If so then, why the inner loop can run for j==0, but not j==1? based on the output of 'code A', at j==1, the loss is sucessfully computed, but when the loss.backward() is trying to use the computational graph of last iteration instead of a new created one, why this happens?